# How to allow user to input and store array using loops- python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, python-requests

I am having an issue with my personal project, my python skills are pretty basic but any help would be greatly appreciated

Question:
TASK 1
To simulate the monitoring required, write a routine that allows entry of the baby’s temperature in
degrees Celsius. The routine should check whether the temperature is within the acceptable range, too
high or too low and output a suitable message in each case.
TASK 2
Write another routine that stores the temperatures taken over a three hour period in an array. This
routine should output the highest and lowest temperatures and calculate the difference between these
temperatures.
NOTE: MORE emphasis on task 2

my failed attempt:

```
from array import array
print("BABY TEMPERATURE CHECKER")
MinBbyTemp = float(36.0)
MaxBbyTemp = float(37.5) 
routTemp = array("i", [])
BabyTemp = float(input("What is the temperature of the baby?"))
if BabyTemp < MinBbyTemp:
   print("The temperature of the baby is low/unusual and needs to be worked on")
elif BabyTemp > MaxBbyTemp:
   print("The temperature of the baby is too high and above the average")
else:
   print("The temperature inputted is out of range")
```

Comment: Have you _tried_ "storing user inputs in an array"? What happened when you did that? BTW, `array.array` is not the go-to "array-like" collection in Python. You normally use _lists_ instead.

Comment: thanks alot i will note that

Comment: you could use `list` for data. Create list before loop and use `appen()` inside loop. `36.0` is already a float number so you don't need `float()`. The same with `37.5`. You would `float()` for string ie. `float("36.0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would recommend using Pythons built-in list type, instead of array.
Secondly, `float(36.0)` is redundant as `36.0` will be inferred as a float by Python.

Your code is actually pretty good, but if you want to enter more than one value, you'll need a loop. This loop would continue forever, so if you wanted it to end you'd need to change `while True` to either `while some_boolean` and let the user change the `some_boolean`, or a `for` loop.

```py
max_temp = 37.5
min_temp = 36.0
recorded_temps = [] # Creates recorded_temps as list.
while True:
    baby_temp = float(input("What is the temperature of the baby?"))
    # Note: if user input cannot be converted to float, this will yield a type error.
    if max_temp < baby_temp:
       print("The temperature of the baby is too high and above the average.")
    elif baby_temp < min_temp:
        print("The temperature of the baby is low/unusual and needs to be worked on.")
    elif (min_temp < baby_temp) and (baby_temp < max_temp):
        print("The temperature is within a healthy range.")

    recorded_temps.append(baby_temp) # Adds baby_temp to recorded_temps.
```

After this loop is executed, you'll have a Python list of temperatures, which you can handle as [Daniel Hao explained.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65461325/13766237)

Answer (score 0):

@EmeluDev - let's try to solve this step by step.  Assuming you've collected the daily temp. measurement already (Task 1 is done). Then starting with Task 2:

```py
# Task 2 Demo Template

dailyTemps = [36.9, 36.7, 37.2, 37.5, 36.8, 38.2]


highest  = max(dailyTemps)
lowest   = min(dailyTemps)
difference = highest - lowest

print(f' highest Temp: {highest}, loweset Temp: {lowest} ')
print(f' the difference is: {difference} ')

Output: 
highest Temp: 38.2, loweset Temp: 36.7 
the difference is: 1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

This Is How I Would Do It:

```python
import sched
import time

#PART 1

print("###BABY TEMPERATURE CHECKER###")

MinBbyTemp = float(36.0)
MaxBbyTemp = float(37.5)

array = []
temp = 0

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

BabyTemp = float(input("What is the temperature of the baby: "))

if BabyTemp < MinBbyTemp:
    print("The temperature of the baby is low/unusual and needs to be worked on")
elif BabyTemp > MaxBbyTemp:
    print("The temperature of the baby is too high and above the average")
else:
    print("The temperature of the baby is normal")

#PART 2

def get_input(string):
    value = input(str(string))
    
    if len(value) > 0:
        return value
    else:
        print("You Must Enter Something! Try Again!")
        get_input(str(string))

def wait(sc):
    global temp
    global array
    
    temp = get_input("Enter The Baby\'s Temperature: ")
    array.append(temp)

def get_max(arr):
    max_ = arr[0]  
         
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == None:
            pass
        else:
            if int(arr[i]) < int(max_):    
                max_ = arr[i]

    return max_

def get_min(arr):
    min_ = arr[0]  
         
    for i in range(0, len(arr)):
        if arr[i] == None:
            pass
        else:
            if int(arr[i]) > int(min_):
                min_ = arr[i]

    return min_
    
for i in range(0, 36):
    s.enter(300, 1, wait, (s,))
    s.run()

    print("{} / 36".format(str(i + 1)))


print(array)

min_temp = get_max(array)
max_temp = get_min(array)
range_temp = int(max_temp) - int(min_temp)

print("The Minimum Temperature Was " + str(min_temp))
print("The Maximum Temperature Was " + str(max_temp))
print("The Range Of Temperature Was " + str(range_temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through my code again and I also saw the following contribution, It really helped
This is what i finally did:

```
    # GCSE TASK (BABY TEMPERATURE)
from array import *
print("BABY TEMPERATURE CHECKER")
MinBbyTemp = 36.0
MaxBbyTemp = 37.5  # in degree Celsius
routTemp = array("i", [])  # array to store routine checks
NoBabyTemp = int(input("How many temperatures are you inputting? "))
for temp in range(NoBabyTemp):
    BabyTemp = int(float(input("What is the temperature of the baby? ")))
    array = [BabyTemp]
    if MaxBbyTemp < BabyTemp:
        print("The temperature of the baby is too high and above the average.")
    elif BabyTemp < MinBbyTemp:
        print("The temperature of the baby is low/unusual and needs to be worked on.")
    elif (BabyTemp > MinBbyTemp) and (BabyTemp < MaxBbyTemp):
        print("The temperature is within a healthy range.")
    else:
        print("The temperature is not acceptable")
    routTemp.append(BabyTemp)
for temp in range(NoBabyTemp):
    print(routTemp[temp], end=" ")
highest = max(routTemp)
lowest = min(routTemp)
difference = highest - lowest
print("The highest temperature is ", highest)
print("The lowest temperature is ", lowest)
print("The difference between", highest, "and", lowest, "=", difference)
# end of code
```

i still had many errors but they were not as tasking to debug